# Python recursive function counting the user

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

The count_users function recursively counts the amount of users that belong to a group in the company system, by going through each of the members of a group and if one of them is a group, recursively calling the function and counting the members. But it has a bug! Can you spot the problem and fix it?

```
def count_users(group):
    count = 0
    for member in get_members(group):
        count += 1
        if is_group(member):
            count += count_users(member)
    return count
print(count_users("sales")) # Should be 3
print(count_users("engineering")) # Should be 8
print(count_users("everyone")) # Should be 18
```

Comment: Can you put example of datas ? and what was expected output vs actual output ?

Answer (score 7):

```
def count_users(group):
    count = 0
    for member in get_members(group):
    #count += 1
        if is_group(member):
            count += count_users(member)
        else:
            count+=1
    return count

print(count_users("sales")) # Should be 3
print(count_users("engineering")) # Should be 8
print(count_users("everyone")) # Should be 18
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies in your for loop. Currently you increase your count by 1 for each "member" of the group, even if that member is a group itself.
Instead move this line into a new else branch after the if is_group(member), so it will only be increased by either the number of members if `member` is a group, or 1 if `member` is not a group.

Answer (score 1):

```
def count_users(group):
  count = 0
  for member in get_members(group):
    count += 1
    if is_group(member):
      count += count_users(member)-1
  return count

print(count_users("sales")) # Should be 3
print(count_users("engineering")) # Should be 8
print(count_users("everyone")) # Should be 18
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the correct solution :

```
def count_users(group):
  count = 0
  for member in get_members(group):
    count += 1
    if is_group(member):
      count += count_users(member)-1
 return count
```

`print(count_users("sales"))` # Should be `3`

`print(count_users("engineering"))` # Should be `8`

`print(count_users("everyone"))` # Should be `18`

Answer (score 1):

```
def count_users(group):
  count = 0
  for member in get_members(group):
    count += 1
    if is_group(member):
      count += count_users(member)
      count -= 1
  return count

print(count_users("sales")) # Should be 3
print(count_users("engineering")) # Should be 8
print(count_users("everyone")) # Should be 18
```

**count -= 1** means that the one one assumed member that turned out to be a group just needs to be eliminated from the count variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_users(group):
  count = 0
  for member in get_members(group):
    #count += 1
    if is_group(member):
      count += count_users(member)
    else:
      count += 1
  return count

print(count_users("sales")) # Should be 3
print(count_users("engineering")) # Should be 8
print(count_users("everyone")) # Should be 18
```